# CMake doesn't include header directory of submodule A within submodule B

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMake project that looks like this:

```
project/
  CMakeLists.txt
  subprojectA/
    CMakeLists.txt
    include/
      headerA.hpp
    src/
      libraryA.cpp
  subprojectB/
    CMakeLists.txt
    src/
      mainB.cpp
```

The "library" subproject, A, is compiled as a static library, becoming libsubprojectA.a. The "main" project, B, is compiled as a binary and depends on the library. mainB.cpp includes a reference to headerA.hpp.

Here is subprojectA/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(SubProjectA)
include_directories(include)
add_library(subprojectA STATIC src/libraryA.cpp)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Include Directories" FORCE)
```

And here is subprojectB/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(SubProjectB)
include_directories(${SubProjectA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(mainBinary src/mainB.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mainBinary subprojectA)
```

The main Project CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
project(Project)
add_subdirectory(subprojectB)
add_subdirectory(subprojectA)
```

Note that subprojectB, the main project, is listed *before* subprojectA.

Here's the problem. When I first run "cmake" on this project, `${SubProjectA_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is not set within SubProjectB.

What I think is happening is that the CMakeLists for SubProjectB loads first, when `${SubProjectA_INCLUDE_DIRS}` has not yet been set. It sets its own include path to an empty string as a result. However, even though `libsubprojectA.a` gets built successfully before `mainBinary`, the include path was already set empty beforehand. As a result, I get this error when trying to make `mainBinary`:

```
subprojectB/src/mainB.cpp:1:23: fatal error: headerA.hpp: No such file or directory
#include "headerA.hpp"
                      ^
```

It's a workaround to put subprojectA before subprojectB in the main Project CMakeLists in the declarative world of CMake. What I really want is to know the proper way to indicate to CMake that the `include_directories(${SubProjectA_INCLUDE_DIRS})` line *depends* on the definitions that exist inside SubProjectA's CMakeLists. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to express that include directory *subprojectA/include* is an **interface** of the library *subprojectA*, attach this property to the target with [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) command:

**subprojectA/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
project(SubProjectA)
add_library(subprojectA STATIC src/libraryA.cpp)
# PUBLIC adds both:
#     1) include directories for compile library and
#     2) include directories for library's interface
target_include_directories(subprojectA PUBLIC include)
```

So any executable(or other library) which linked with *subprojectA* will have this include directory automatically:

**subprojectB/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
project(SubProjectB)
add_executable(mainBinary src/mainB.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mainBinary subprojectA)
```

Of course, for use last command properly you need to process directory with library **before** one with executable:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
project(Project)
add_subdirectory(subprojectA)
add_subdirectory(subprojectB)
```

Comment: The very last part, regarding the ordering of the references to the subdirectories, is the biggest element of this. Despite CMake's design as a generally declarative language, it still has elements that just have to be in the right order. So I guess that's the best I'll be able to do for now. Thanks.